# In ConEmu how to pause on click

Tags: conemu

Windows cmd.exe pauses execution on left click,
how do I achieve the same in ConEmu?

Currently it selects the text but executes and scrolls forwards.

(useful for inspecting mass amount of output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just press the <kbd>Pause</kbd> button.

Docs: https://conemu.github.io/en/AlternativeBuffer.html

Comment: Oh yeah, I always wondered what that button does :D cheers